# element with the max height from a set of elements

Tags: jquery

I have a set of `div` elements. In `jQuery`, I would like to be able to find out the `div` with the maximum height and also the height of that `div`. For instance:

```
<div>
    <div class="panel">
      Line 1
      Line 2
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      Line 1<br/>
      Line 2<br/>
      Line 3<br/>
      Line 4<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      Line 1
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      Line 1
      Line 2
    </div>
</div>
```

By looking at the above, we know that the 2nd `div` (with 4 Lines) has the maximum height of all. How do I find this out? Could someone please help?

So far I've tried:

`$("div.panel").height()` which returns the height of the 1st `div`.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) and [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Examples).

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $("div.panel").map(function ()
{
    return $(this).height();
}).get());
```

---

If that's confusing to read, this might be clearer:

```
var heights = $("div.panel").map(function ()
    {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get();

maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
```

Comment: This finds the highest height but not a reference to the actual element.

Comment: You're right; I wasn't clear that the OP wants the element as well. Your answer works in that case.

Comment: Matt: Thank you so much. Yes, all I wanted was the max height and not the reference.

Comment: Ah, great! Next time you might want to be a bit clearer in the question - but I guess you got your point across well enough `:)`

Comment: does this code work's if height is not mention in css or earlier in page.

Comment: @MattBall Why the get function, may I ask? What does it do and what's its purpose?

Comment: @chodorowicz glad you asked. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4795529/139010), under the second heading.

Comment: @MattBall Thanks. So jQuery .map return array-like object and get .get turns it into array. But it seems that Math.max works easily on both of these types (just tested in Chrome console), so in this case .get seems unnecessary. Or am I wrong?

Comment: How to deal with 'Infinite'?

Comment: What if `div.panel` element loading dynamically ?

Answer (score 20):

The html that you posted should use some `<br>` to actually have divs with different heights. Like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="panel">
      Line 1<br>
      Line 2
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      Line 1<br>
      Line 2<br>
      Line 3<br>
      Line 4
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      Line 1
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      Line 1<br>
      Line 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Apart from that, if you want a reference to the div with the max height you can do this:

```
var highest = null;
var hi = 0;
$(".panel").each(function(){
  var h = $(this).height();
  if(h > hi){
     hi = h;
     highest = $(this);  
  }    
});
//highest now contains the div with the highest so lets highlight it
highest.css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: Be careful with this one, if you don't use a jQuery method inside (like `.height` in this case) then you must dereference it, ex: ` $(this)[0].scrollHeight;`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to reuse in multiple places:

```
var maxHeight = function(elems){
    return Math.max.apply(null, elems.map(function ()
    {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get());
}
```

Then you can use:

```
maxHeight($("some selector"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function startListHeight($tag) {
  
    function setHeight(s) {
        var max = 0;
        s.each(function() {
            var h = $(this).height();
            max = Math.max(max, h);
        }).height('').height(max);
    }
  
    $(window).on('ready load resize', setHeight($tag));
}

jQuery(function($) {
    $('#list-lines').each(function() {
        startListHeight($('li', this));
    });
});
```

```css
#list-lines {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#list-lines li {
    float: left;
    display: table;
    width: 33.3334%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#list-lines li img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#list-lines::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list-lines">
    <li>
        <img src="http://img2.vetton.ru//upl/1000/346/138/vetton_ru_sddu7-2560x1600.jpg" alt="" />
        <br /> Line 1
        <br /> Line 2
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://img2.vetton.ru//upl/1000/346/138/vetton_ru_mixwall66-2560x1600.jpg" alt="" />
        <br /> Line 1
        <br /> Line 2
        <br /> Line 3
        <br /> Line 4
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://img2.vetton.ru//upl/1000/346/138/vetton_ru_sddu7-2560x1600.jpg" alt="" />
        <br /> Line 1
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://img2.vetton.ru//upl/1000/346/138/vetton_ru_mixwall66-2560x1600.jpg" alt="" />
        <br /> Line 1
        <br /> Line 2
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul, li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul li {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://img2.vetton.ru//upl/1000/346/138/vetton_ru_sddu7-2560x1600.jpg" alt="">
    <br> Line 1
    <br> Line 2
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://img2.vetton.ru//upl/1000/346/138/vetton_ru_mixwall66-2560x1600.jpg" alt="">
    <br> Line 1
    <br> Line 2
    <br> Line 3
    <br> Line 4
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://img2.vetton.ru//upl/1000/346/138/vetton_ru_sddu7-2560x1600.jpg" alt="">
    <br> Line 1
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://img2.vetton.ru//upl/1000/346/138/vetton_ru_mixwall66-2560x1600.jpg" alt="">
    <br> Line 1
    <br> Line 2
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Find out divs height and setting div height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313140/find-out-divs-height-and-setting-div-height)
(Similar to the one Matt posted but using a loop)

Answer (score 0):

If you were interested in sorting entirely in standard JavaScript, or without using forEach():

```
var panels = document.querySelectorAll("div.panel");

// You'll need to slice the node_list before using .map()
var heights = Array.prototype.slice.call(panels).map(function (panel) {
    // return an array to hold the item and its value
    return [panel, panel.offsetHeight];
}),

// Returns a sorted array
var sortedHeights = heights.sort(function(a, b) { return a[1] > b[1]});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest and clearest way I'd say is:**

```
var maxHeight = 0, maxHeightElement = null;
$('.panel').each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
       maxHeight = $(this).height();
       maxHeightElement = $(this);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful, in some way. Fixing some code from @diogo

```
$(window).on('load',function(){

// get the maxHeight using innerHeight() function
  var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $("div.panel").map(function ()                                                        {
    return $(this).innerHeight();
  }).get());
  
// Set the height to all .panel elements
  $("div.panel").height( maxHeight );
  
});
```