# Find max height of div by dynamic content in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

I have one div and more than one data comes into this div by jstl tag. I want to find max content div height.
I have seen one link but it is show in alert every time 20.
[element with the max height from a set of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060992/element-with-the-max-height-from-a-set-of-elements)

JSP

```
     <div id="div-height" class='cat-product-name'>${i.name} </div>
```

JAVA SCRIPT

```
  $(window).load(function () {
  var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $("#div-height").map(function ()
                {
                    return $(this).height();
                }).get());
                alert(maxHeight);
});
```

[image]

I want to find max height of div and set this height of every div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxHeight = -1;

  $('.cat-product-name').each(function() {
    maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight :     $(this).height();
 });

 $('.cat-product-name').each(function() {
   $(this).height(maxHeight);
 });
});
```

Reference - [Use jQuery/CSS to find the tallest of all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781031/use-jquery-css-to-find-the-tallest-of-all-elements)

Comment: thanks for save my time. If u like my answer then please voting up to help others.

Comment: Yes it will work on images, it all depends on which all elements height you are concerned with and then set image(s) height the max value - $(this).find("img").height(maxHeight);

Answer (score 0):

Each element id on the page must be unique, i.e. you can't have multiple elements with

```
id="div-height"
```

Try using class instead (`class="div-height"`). Note you'll have to adjust your jQuery selector as well to

```
$(".div-height")
```

Comment: It is correct but how to assign this height in div.

Answer (score 0):

A modern take to this problem is the usage of css flex-box with `align-items: stretch;` :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  
  width: 250px;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  outline: 5px solid #888;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Small content</div>
  <div>This divs content needs more height than their siblings!</div>
  <div>Some more text</div>
  <div>Other text</div>
</div>
```