# How to get max height of elements by classname useing javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to get max height of elements by classname useing javascript ?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test</div>
<div class="test">test<br>test</div>
<div class="test">test<br>test<br>test</div>

<script>
 var test_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
 for (var i = 0; i < test_elements.length; i++) {
  var test_elements_width = $(test_elements[i]).height();
  alert(test_elements_width);
 }
</script>
```

I use this code for get all of div height, when test this code, it's will be alert  `18 90 36 and 54`, it's work good.

But i want to set max value of height in this case is `90` to `var max_height` , how can i do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [element with the max height from a set of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060992/element-with-the-max-height-from-a-set-of-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just initialize max_height to `0` and set it to `Math.max` of itself and each div height:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test</div>
<div class="test">test<br>test</div>
<div class="test">test<br>test<br>test</div>

<script>
  var test_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
  var max_height = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < test_elements.length; i++) {
    var test_elements_width = $(test_elements[i]).height();
    alert(test_elements_width);
    max_height = Math.max(max_height, test_elements_width);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to *spread* the mapped `height`s into `Math.max`:

```js
console.log(Math.max(
  ...[...document.querySelectorAll('.test')]
    .map(test => $(test).height())
));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test</div>
<div class="test">test<br>test</div>
<div class="test">test<br>test<br>test</div>
```

Or, with more jQuery:

```js
console.log(Math.max(
  ...$('.test')
    .map((i, test) => $(test).height())
    .get()
));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test</div>
<div class="test">test<br>test</div>
<div class="test">test<br>test<br>test</div>
```